# Why is Navi staring at this puddle like an idiot in the cow cave on Death Mountain?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

The title pretty much sums it up.  I've tried bombing the puddle and scooping it with a bottle, but no luck.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Isn't there a fish in there?

Comment: Nope. I would have figured that out, promise.

Comment: If you play Epona's Song to the cow, and you have an empty bottle, the cow will give you Lon Lon milk.

Comment: I did do that, but I always hate getting milk and potions and stuff.  Just give me faeries and I'm good.

Comment: You've got the answer in your title - "like an idiot".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try using the Sun Song or Song of Storms here - often this means that there is a special sort of fairy present that can fill your life and your magic. You can't, however, keep these fairies in jars.

Usually something in the area determines what song you should play - since there is water present, the song of storms would be your best bet.

Answer (score 8):

In areas where Navi turns green you can usually get something to happen by playing the Song of Storms, the Sun Song or the Scarecrow song.

From the screenshot you included it should be the Sun Song or the Song of Storms from memory.

Answer (score 1):

I played Song of Storms there, and a golden ball appeared that restored all my health and magic when it touched me. I couldn't catch it in a bottle, though.

Answer (score 0):

The Song Of Storms summons a big, reddish-pink fairy, there's one in the Shadow Temple, too, and, near the little river/pond in Hyrule Field...there are more, too. Just look for Navi randomly flying around a place, green in colour. :D

Also, that grotto with the cow in it, in Death Mountain, is pretty...I just love it!! <3

Comment: This cave does not contain a Great Fairy.

Answer (score -3):

In Ocarina of Time, whenever she is green and you don't know what to do, I think you have to play ***Zelda's Lullaby***. Because I did it to a grave and a Poe came out of it.